# what's the difference between d.update(dict(a=1, b=2)) and d.update(dict('a'=1, 'b'=2))

Tags: python, dictionary

I have tried two ways to update a dictionary in python:

1. `d.update(dict(a=1, b=2))`
    This one worked well.
2. `d.update(dict('a'=1, 'b'=2))`
    but , this way gave me a 
   `SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression`
   What's wrong with the second statement? Why it must be `a` rather than `'a'`?
   Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The parameters in a function call must be identifiers, not string constants.

For the same reason you can't write:

```
"a" = 1
```

You also can't call a function

```
dict("a"=5)
```

Instead write:

```
a = 5
dict(a=5)
```

If you need to create a dictionary from a string constant, use literal syntax:

```
{"a": 5, "b": 17}
```

If you need to use strings for variable names when calling a function, the syntax is a bit more strange:

```
func(**{"a": 5}) # more or less equivalent to func(a=5)
```

But note that the `.update` function can be called this way to begin with:

```
d.update(a=1, b=2)
```

Answer (score 2):

A **parameter must be an identifier**. `a` is an identifier. `'a'` is not, it is a string literal (which is a form of an expression).

In Python, you can however use two asterisks to pass a dictionary as a list of *named* parameters. So:

```
d.update(**{'a': 1, 'b': 2})
```

will work. But with such dictionary literal, that is of course useless. You can however construct a dictionary `d2` at runtime, and then call `somefunc(**d2)` to call the function with the keys of `d2` as parameter names, and the corresponding values as values associated with these parameter names.

Comment: @DanielRoseman: sure. I added a short discription for a more useful usecase.